# Memory Usage keeps on increasing

Tags: go, redis

I am using redis-client to connect to redis and do some operations. I am seeing that memory size of the program keeps on increasing. i tried to do pprof.

```
go tool pprof --alloc_space heap.out

Showing nodes accounting for 1.90GB, 91.70% of 2.07GB total
Dropped 87 nodes (cum <= 0.01GB)
Showing top 10 nodes out of 61
flat flat% sum% cum cum%
0.92GB 44.47% 44.47% 1.31GB 63.31% github.com/go-redis/redis/v8.stringInterfaceMapParser
0.44GB 21.32% 65.79% 0.44GB 21.32% github.com/go-redis/redis/v8/internal/proto.(*Reader).readStringReply
0.15GB 7.12% 72.90% 0.15GB 7.12% github.com/godror/godror/dsn.newParamsArray (inline)
0.09GB 4.24% 77.15% 1.58GB 76.54% github.com/go-redis/redis/v8.cmdable.XRange
0.08GB 3.75% 80.90% 0.08GB 3.75% github.com/go-redis/redis/v8.NewXMessageSliceCmd (inline)
0.07GB 3.47% 84.36% 0.12GB 5.92% github.com/godror/godror/dsn.paramsArray.WriteTo
0.06GB 2.83% 87.19% 1.40GB 67.67% github.com/go-redis/redis/v8.xMessageSliceParser
0.04GB 1.96% 89.15% 0.04GB 1.96% strings.(*Builder).Write
0.03GB 1.60% 90.76% 0.04GB 2.08% github.com/godror/godror.(*statement).bindVars
0.02GB 0.94% 91.70% 0.33GB 15.91% github.com/godror/godror.(*conn).initTZ
```

```
go tool pprof heap.out

Showing nodes accounting for 2052.21kB, 100% of 2052.21kB total
Showing top 10 nodes out of 37
flat flat% sum% cum cum%
1028kB 50.09% 50.09% 1028kB 50.09% bufio.NewReaderSize (inline)
512.19kB 24.96% 75.05% 512.19kB 24.96% runtime.malg
512.02kB 24.95% 100% 512.02kB 24.95% github.com/go-redis/redis/v8/internal/proto.(*Reader).readStringReply
0 0% 100% 1028kB 50.09% bufio.NewReader (inline)
0 0% 100% 1540.02kB 75.04% github.com/go-redis/redis/v8.(*Client).Process
0 0% 100% 512.02kB 24.95% github.com/go-redis/redis/v8.(*StringSliceCmd).readReply
0 0% 100% 512.02kB 24.95% github.com/go-redis/redis/v8.(*StringSliceCmd).readReply.func1
0 0% 100% 1028kB 50.09% github.com/go-redis/redis/v8.(*baseClient)._getConn
0 0% 100% 1540.02kB 75.04% github.com/go-redis/redis/v8.(*baseClient)._process
0 0% 100% 1540.02kB 75.04% github.com/go-redis/redis/v8.(*baseClient)._process.func1
```

But not able to figure out why memory is increasing?

Comment: What are you actually doing inside your code? What are the operations?

Comment: I am reading the data from redis and pushing to oracle DB.

Comment: You are looking at allocations, not used memory. Allocations are counters. They will never decrease.